# Add Loading image in web page when it take too much time to load

Tags: loading

Some of my web page take long time to load. I want to find loading image which fulfill the following requirement;

1. working properly in IE 11
2. loading image must be located at center
3. transparent background
4. (Optional) it will show the loading image immediately after clicking any button. During loading, it can't do anything in the page
   (Preventing Double Form Submission)

Thanks,
Tony

Answer (score 0):

```
    <!-- jQuery Plugin -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- Preloader --><script type="text/javascript">// <![CDATA[
$(window).load(function() { $("#spinner").fadeOut("slow"); })
// ]]></script>
```

Let’s add some CSS to give it a beautiful look and show the image in the middle of the screen

```
#spinner {
position: fixed;
left: 0px;
top: 0px;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
z-index: 9999;
background: url(your/image/path/loading.png) 50% 50% no-repeat #ede9df;
}
```

And in the last, add this html right below the opening body tag

```
<!-- Preloader -->
<div id="spinner"></div>
```